# How to load a ComboBox with Items from a text file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, text-files

What is the simplest way of importing items from a text file into a `ComboBox` control?  The text file contains multiple lines.  I need to add each line from the text file as an item in the combo box.

Comment: What's the format of the text file?  One item per line?  What type of combo box?  WinForm, ASP, WPF?

Comment: one item per line. havent a clue what WinForm, ASP, WPTF are am just ussing vb.net

Comment: WinForm vs. ASP vs. WPF is the type of UI technology you are using.  All of these (and others) are types of UI's which are supported by VB.NET.  Typically, the type of UI you are using is determined by the project template you choose when you created your project.  If you chose "Windows Application", then it's using WinForm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the format of the text file is one combo box item per line, and you want to load them into a WinForm `ComboBox` control, then this would be the simplest way to do it:

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
```

You'll need to add `Imports System.IO` to the top of the code file.  Either that or specify the full name of the `File` class:

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
```

Comment: This is starting to go the right direction though now i get an error  Name 'File'is not declared.?

Comment: sorry its a simple thing though im more home with visual lisp (autocad programing) thanks

Comment: No problem.  I understand.  We were all beginners at everything once :)  Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways of doing it. These are two ways you can do it with error handling:

## 1

```
Try
  ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
  Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(File Path)
  
  Do While Not objReader.EndOfStream
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(objReader.ReadLine)
     Loop
  objReader.Close() 
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(Messege)
End Try
```

## 2

```
Try
  ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
  ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(Messege)
End Try
```

Either one of these will work for you. It is always good practice to use error handling so your program doesn't crash and can do something else in case it fails to read the file. I did add a ComboBox1.Items.Clear() in the beginning because what will end up happening is if you have your code in a subroutine where it is refreshing and constantly reading the text file live, it will keep on adding to the list the the things that are already in the combobox and will have repeated values. For Example, lets say you have in the textfile the words EARTH MARS In the combobox, you will have the word EARTH MARS. But if you have it to refresh constantly lets just say 4 times, the combobox will now display EARTH MARS EARTH MARS EARTH MARS EARTH MARS. Now if you use my code, it will read EARTH MARS and put in the combobox EARTH MARS and if it refreshes 4 or how many ever times, it will still display EARTH MARS because it is clearing the items in the combobox before going back to the textfile and reading what is on it. Now if you add the word JUPITER to the text file, your combobox will now append the word JUPITER to the combobox items list, and voila, nor repeated values.

Answer (score 1):

`ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(local path))`

Ex:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\zone\target.txt"))

  End Sub
```

notice, under form_load trigger